# How to map JSONB on projection's field in Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have table in `PostgreSQL` with field of `JSONB` type, the entity looks like that:

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_table")
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType::class)
class TestEntity(

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "test_id")
    var main: Main? = null,

    @Column(name = "id")
    val id: String,

    @Column(name = "fallback_id")
    var fallbackId: String? = null,

    @Column(name = "properties", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    val properties: MutableMap<String, Any> = mutableMapOf(),
```

And `projection` like that:

```kotlin
interface TestProjection {
    val id: String
    val fallbackId: String
    val properties: MutableMap<String, Any>
}
```

I want to retrieve from database and map to this `projection`(with `JSONB` field as a map), but when I tried to do so using this `repository`:

```kotlin
@Repository
interface TestRepository : JpaRepository<TestEntity, UUID> {
fun findByFallbackIdIn(fallbackIds: Set<String>): Set<TestEntity>

@Query(
        nativeQuery = true,
        value = """
               SELECT 
                     cast(t.id as varchar) as id,
                     cast(t.fallback_id as varchar) as fallback_id,
                     t.properties as properties,
               FROM test_table t
               AND t.id < :last_uuid
               ORDER by t.id DESC
               LIMIT :batch_size
            """
    )
    fun findTestForSomeLogic(
        @Param("last_uuid") lastUuid: UUID,
        @Param("batch_size") batchSize: Int,
    ): List<TestProjection>
}
```

I got exception from hibernate:

```
No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
```

**So how to map `JSONB` to projection's field?**